# New laptop, WIFI card not working

Tags: wireless

I have recently bought a GP66 leopard 11uh laptop, and while it's mostly working fine, I am having trouble getting the WIFI card to work on this laptop in ubuntu. The drivers and firmware are installed I believe, and I am on 21.04. The wifi card is a Killer Wi-Fi 6E AX1675. I currently have a usb wifi adapter installed, but I would like to get this internal one working.

So far, I have found out via this link that the wifi card is basically a branded AX210;
http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/killer-wi-fi-6e-ax1675.835669/

Which should be supported by intel:
https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

However it unfortunately is not working. The drivers and firmware are installed I believe, it's just not showing up. I've included some relevant outputs I got while attempting to get this device to work. Thank you for your time and help!

'''

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-usb:1                   
       description: Wireless interface
       product: 802.11 bg WLAN
       vendor: Ralink
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@3:3
       logical name: wlx001cf08a304c
       version: 0.01
       serial: 00:1c:f0:8a:30:4c
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt73usb driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic firmware=1.7 ip=192.168.86.227 link=yes maxpower=300mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 04
       serial: d8:bb:c1:21:71:58
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:82300000-8230ffff memory:82310000-82313fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:82200000-82203fff
'''

'''
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks Device [1a56:1674]
'''

'''
ls /lib/firmware | grep 8000
iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
'''
```

EDIT: I already have the firmware installed, it's still not working for some reason.

Comment: Ok, So I have Dell Alienware with the Killer wifi adapter, I have install Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel version 5.15.--46. I had the same issue, I tried many solutions but non of them worked for me. What worked for me is given in the following link:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058909/wireless.html

Answer (score 0):

You will find the driver of your Intel AX210 WiFi 6E card on follow Link:

```
* https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html
* https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-ty-59.601f3a66.0.tgz
```

Or you use a .deb packet:

```
https://pkgs.org/download/firmware-iwlwifi
```

Comment: I already have the firmware installed, It's still not working for some reason.

Comment: I tried installing the .deb you suggested, but It's not working with sudo dpkg -i ? I'm pretty sure the firmware is already in there

Comment: @Mitch did you find a solution to this?  I have the same problem.  The drivers are exist in /lib/firmware as part of the default ubuntu 21.04 distro and the kernel version (5.11) should support, but the device is not being claimed.  (BT loads np).  Is AX1675 somehow different to AX210?

Comment: I have also tried installing popOS AND Debian - but same result: cannot configure the card.  At this point I think I will try updating the kernel to the mainline 5.13 kernel and seeing if that supports... or try Arch

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I have not been able to find a solution as of yet. I ended up  just using WSL on windows for now as much as it pains me. Intel said that this wifi card is not supported on linux, despite it being listed as suported when I bought it. I'm going to try again today but if it does not work I will likely switch the card out for something with compatibilty.

Comment: @Mitch - I can confirm wifi card is working on latest build of Ubuntu 21.10 (which I just finished installing a few minutes ago)
Final 21.10 release is still 8 weeks away.. the current build seems pretty stable and it does work with the ax210/ax1675 wifi card.  (GE66 11uh)

Comment: Thank you drew! You beat me to it lol. I'm downloading it now.

Comment: I have a MSI stealth GS66 11uh and unfortunately updating to 21.10 did not solved the issue for me. I'm not even able to boot the default kernel release and I had to use an older one, otherwise my drive was not détected...

Answer (score 0):

if you still have this problem try to install `backport-iwlwifi`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
sudo reboot
```

This helped me to enable my Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1675i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (211NGW) in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Unfortunately it has low download speed (23Mbps) then on Windows (60Mbps) if I am not near my router.